# Automating downtime (non-non-downtime) upgrades in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

We're moving a legacy app to Kubernetes. We will have many instances of it running (a Kubernetes namespace per customer), so we want to automate our application upgrade process.

Kubernetes has well established patterns for rolling upgrades, but I can't use them (yet). My application requires the following process:

1. all existing pods are deleted
2. a database upgrade job (Kubernetes Job) runs and completes successfully
3. new pods are created

We define the pods through a Deployment. The database upgrade job is idempotent as long as we never run more than one at a time.

I assume my workflow is not an uncommon one for legacy applications, and yet I can't find any established patterns or tools preconfigured. Is there something out there? If I do have to write my own operator (or use something like Kudo), what is the best set of steps for it to perform?

Comment: Hi @Jesse, did the solution of mdaniel help you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is an existing process for that:

1. Use the `kubectl scale` command to scale down the existing Deployment to zero replicas: `kubectl scale --replicas=0 deploy/my-legacy-deployment`
2. Wait for that to stabilize (there's your requested downtime ;-)

   Using `kubectl wait` will be helpful, although I personally don't have experience introducing downtime in order to know the remaining arguments to `wait` to suggest here

   You can also use something like `while true; do [[ 0 -eq $(kubectl get pods -o name -l legacy-deployment-selector | wc -l) ]] && break; done` to stall until there are no pods remaining
3. Run your database job, or migrations of your choosing
4. Deploy the new version as you normally would; depending on the tool you use, this may or may not actually influence the currently zero-scaled Deployment

   For example, `kubectl set image deploy/my-legacy-deployment "*=example.com/my/new/image"` will leave the Deployment at zero replicas

   But a `helm install --upgrade legacy whatever-else` may very well set the Deployment's replicas to the value found in the chart
5. If your tool has not yet scaled up the new Deployment, you can now set it back to the desired value with the opposite command: `kubectl scale --replicas=3 deploy/my-legacy-deployment`

Answer (score 0):

We ended up using [ArgoCD](https://argoproj.github.io/cd/) with its [sync phases and waves feature](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/sync-waves/).

The short version is to use sync phases to apply chart updates (via ArgoCD) in stages:

1. Run a job that sets the deployment's replica count to 0
2. Run a job that applies schema changes for the new version
3. Update the deployment with the new container image and the desired replica count

I wrote a blog post with more details for those that are interested: https://jessemcdowell.ca/2023/06/Automating-Non-Non-Downtime-Upgrades-in-Kubernetes-with-ArgoCD/